# Unable to disable a startup message in Zsh

Tags: startup, zsh

I get the following when I start my Zsh.

```
Usage: prompt <options>
Options:
    -c              Show currently selected theme and parameters
    -l              List currently available prompt themes
    -p [<themes>]   Preview given themes (defaults to all)
    -h [<theme>]    Display help (for given theme)
    -s <theme>      Set and save theme
    <theme>         Switch to new theme immediately (changes not saved)
```

It seems to be set by some theme file, since the same text is [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-48/zsh/Functions/Prompts/promptinit).

**How can you disable the notification in Zsh?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a startup message. It's the error/default help message displayed when the `prompt` command is used without arguments or erroneous arguments. Find out where you're using it, and fix/delete it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The following line caused me the bug: autoload promptinit && promptinit && prompt minimal_vcs. I am not sure what it does. I got from http://github.com/mattfoster/zshkit/commit/18b02bb563cfa957a1e08b75bf10116ffa518166 initially.

Comment: You're trying to use a prompt, but the definition of that prompt isn't there because you haven't installed/written them. So prompt doesn't know how to use them, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to search through the files that zsh loads on startup, here is a [list from their documentation](http://zsh.dotsrc.org/Guide/zshguide02.html#l9)

Look for a misconfigured prompt command line and try commenting it out or better fixing it.